# Is Adobe Lightroom v6.0 (standalone and NOT cloud) serial# stored in a file on my Mac?

Tags: adobe-lightroom

Which file on MAC OS is the Adobe lightroom v6.0 serial# is stored? I've looked at /Library/Application Support/Adobe PCD/ - the cache files, but that only has the trial license and NOT my license key.

Comment: Why do you need the license key?

Comment: I bought it from a 3rd party a while ago. And did not register with adobe. I am getting rid of my old mac where the install is and would like my product to be installed on my new mac. But I do not have the key and am hoping when i installed it on my old mac the serial# I provided is stored some place on the OS.

Comment: It is advisable to go through Adobe Lightroom license terms & conditions to determine if such license transfer is covered. It is recommended you register with Adobe. Typically conditions for such transfers from one machine to another are covered in license agreement. On another note, how did you manage to get it working on your first Mac. Possibly you can follow the same steps to get it working on the new machine.

Comment: If I remember correctly, LR6 doesn't have a installation key per se.  You have a "proof of purchase" key that you submit to Adobe which then gives you a key for installation.

Comment: So basically the key is not on a file encrypted or in a .db on the OS, it it? @Allan

Comment: I don't believe so.  I think after LR4 they started using an activation model rather than a key - unfortunately, I don't have access to the software to verify so I'm not codifying it with a bona fide answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Migration Assistant to migrate your Home folder, Applications & Settings from your old Mac to the new one. This often transfers app licenses & settings successfully between computers.